# How to encrypt XML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, encryption

Is it possible to Encrypt XML with JavaScript(In browser, not nodejs)? If yes, How could I do that? Is there any particular JavaScript library?

I provided an example of an encryption which I implemented in C#:

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Method id="D67EFAEF-BA51-4B07-B08A-38295C9853B4">
    <TokenID>DBEF4FC7-9213-4DE3-BD49-8BB76BE3F891</TokenID>
    <ID>8B430943-0CE5-404F-A920-5D224BCD6A07</ID>
</Method>
```

**Sample encrypted XML with RijndaelManaged and EncryptedXml in C#:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>shared-key</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>knP+Mg40Ls/qau+yBgNp/pKP39TKWTYR5+2d+1ZjiP0hNwPzvK+qAzzxpyJHajA6FFiZbVzlEYNZn8E0Y55wvSthTRfx09oaVN400ADQrGP4ZfY2HD4XbWLCkA1skHggXro/eBA4YwnH0m9chmtTi7T+dawjTdPZ9RD9GMG70ew=</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
</KeyInfo>
<CipherData>
    <CipherValue>kMdYGUUludy5q3oMLGJCYeGhfqNYrSg/Rsuhrmp/vWyMuaKbEIeJuNngaNq3fcCwEoPhnuN0nkdALgifQFqGLUYkDLnlaHhOBfP0l7c1xOtYeq2tshaONY1r6cOVG6fnsYUGCTFIkM1+G3igEHJbQ3LpyJcn5OoxesgVetjeAnu1QL6F08sGGFkk8f6m8BrdsNSRD56PccfzKEXgWBO87Z8swjxr9caynaE1a9Zd8e8=</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

Comment: Can Javascript do encryption on text? Yes. Is XML text? Yes. So: yes. Beyond this it becomes a bit vague what you actually need or want to know.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it? 99%+ of cases where encrypting data in a web browser is designed are handled transparently by using SSL.

Comment: Where does the key come from?

Comment: Btw, it would be better if you [edit]ed your questions instead of deleting them and reposting them.

Answer (score 1):

In my hybrid apps I use Google's [cryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for encryption offline storage. I use JSON and I need to stringify/parse before encryption/decryption, I suppose that can be done somehow for XML too.